# get path of an uploaded file

Tags: forms, files

This is my form to upload a photo

```
 $form['Background_image'] = array(
 '#type' => 'managed_file',
 '#title' => t('Choose a background image'),
 '#description' => t('Click "Browse..." to select an image to upload.'),
 '#required' => TRUE,
 '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('jpeg jpg png gif')),
'#upload_location' => 'public://backgroundimage/',
 '#default_value' => $this->options['Background_image'],

);
```

I tried this function that get the current uploaded image and return its path, but still not working: what is missing:

```
function image_path()
  {
   $f = file_load($this->options['Background_image']);
  //this too is not working: 
  //$f = file_load($form_state['values']['Background_image']);
   $url_image = file_create_url($f->uri);
   print_r($url_image);
   return ($url_image);
  }
```

Comment: can you check if you are getting the value of `$f->uri`, if not than can you try $f = $form_state['values']['Background_image'];

Comment: Whats `$this` in your current context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this is surprising in your form! I am not sure but do not consider $this as reference  of current uploaded file,if the code you have shared is complete code then if you try to look inside dpm($this) , you will get your answer why file is not loading.
check [this link](http://www.lilianagaete.com/how-to-do-a-file-upload-in-drupal-7/), it explains how to create custom upload form.

the use of `file_create_url()` is appropriate to get file url from uri,so I am sharing the submit handler changed codes from reference link the submit handler showing use of

```
function import_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Load the file.
  $file = file_load($form_state['values']['file_fid']);
  // Change status to permanent.
  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
  // Save.
  $uploaded = file_save($file);
  if ($uploaded == TRUE) {
    drupal_set_message(t('The file has been uploaded.'));
    dpm(file_create_url($file->uri));
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('The file could not be uploaded. Please contact the site administrator.'), 'error');
  }

}
```

Comment: when I tried  drupal_set_message(t( dpm(file_create_url($file->uri))));to see the file path but drupal dispays:http://localhost:8080/TestD3/  (link of my site)

Comment: please do debugging and use dpm() without drupal_set_messgage() and t(), it looks like you are able to upload the file properly , check the upload location you are providing in the form field.

Answer (score 0):

In your submit handler of your form, you should be able to retrieve the `fid` of the uploaded file / image. By using this `fid`, you can load the file and work with that object.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_FORM_NAME_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    $fid = $form_state['values']['Background_image'];

    if ($fid !== 0) {
        // Retrieve image URL
        $image_url = YOUR_MODULE_get_file_url(file_load($fid));
    }
}

function YOUR_MODULE_get_file_url($file)
{
    if (!$file) {
        // File not found
        return false;
    }

    // Return URL from a give file URI
    return file_create_url($file->uri);
}
```